# tikz align text to left inside node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to align node text to left but it seems below code still put the text at the center of node:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \node[draw,rectangle,minimum width=10em,align=left] (A) {Abc};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: output]

Update:
Thanks for your valuable comments, so I should update it as following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \node[draw,rectangle,minimum height=4em,text width=10em,align=left] (A) {Abc};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then it's exactly what I want:

[image]

Comment: It's `text width` for the text boxes, minimum width is for the shape.

Comment: Oh, so that means I should use "text width" instead of "minimum width" or should use both?

Comment: When you set text width, it already increases the shape dimensions to cover that text box so you get it as a bonus, but for example you want a taller node then you can use together with `minimum height=2cm`.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.